# JSPM Bootstrap 4 isn't grabbing scss folder

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jspm

I am trying to use JSPM to install Bootstrap 4 Alpha. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/v4.0.0-alpha.2

I want to be able to grab everything on that page. If I do `npm install  bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.2` I am able to get the scss folder and its contents.

[image: NPM]

However if I do `jspm install bootstrap=npm:bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.2` I only get:

[image: JSPM]

I am not quite sure how to make jspm grab the `scss` folder and its contents. Nor am I sure why it isn't grabbing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap's package.json contains the following jspm config:

```
"jspm": {
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "*"
  },
  "directories": {
    "lib": "dist"
  },
  "ignore": [
    "dist/js/npm"
  ],
  "main": "js/bootstrap",
  "shim": {
    "js/bootstrap": {
      "deps": [
        "jquery"
      ],
      "exports": "$"
    }
  }
},
```

As you can see it defines that for jspm only the dist folder is important. Therefore, jspm ignores the rest.

You need to create an override like it is described in the docs in order to change the `directories.lib` setting and other related options like `main`:

https://github.com/jspm/registry/wiki/Configuring-Packages-for-jspm#testing-configuration

Upd, the full command would look:

```
 jspm install npm:bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.2 -o "{\"dependencies\": {  \"jquery\": \"*\" }, \"directories\": {  \"lib\": \".\" }, \"ignore\": [  \"dist/js/npm\" ], \"main\": \"dist/js/bootstrap\", \"shim\": {  \"dist/js/bootstrap\": {   \"deps\": [    \"jquery\"   ],   \"exports\": \"$\"  } }}"
```

Comment: you mentioned `directories.lib` I've read the docs however I couldn't find what/where file to modify is it package.json or the jspm ones ?, also if you don't mind would you be able to provide an example or gist ?

Comment: Did you see the link I posted?

the command for your package: `


jspm install npm:bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.2 -o "{\"dependencies\": {  \"jquery\": \"*\" }, \"directories\": {  \"lib\": \".\" }, \"ignore\": [  \"dist/js/npm\" ], \"main\": \"dist/js/bootstrap\", \"shim\": {  \"dist/js/bootstrap\": {   \"deps\": [    \"jquery\"   ],   \"exports\": \"$\"  } }}""
`

Comment: As an FYI, you can manually inject that json into your package.json file into jspm.overrides. To get bootstrap 3 css to be included, I had to use this: "overrides": {
      "npm:bootstrap@3.3.6": {
        "files": [
          "dist",
          "fonts",
          "js",
          "less",
          "package.json"
        ],
        "main": "js/bootstrap",
        "shim": {
          "js/bootstrap": {
            "deps": [
              "jquery"
            ],
            "exports": "$"
          }
        }
      }
    }